# How to add clickable http link in expandablelistview's submenu in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to add a download link for pdf file in expandable list view submenu: **when i expand the parent and I click on one of the submenu it should open the browser or start downloading the file**.

It will be good if get a complete tutorial for this as i just started android developing.

There are good tutorials for creating expandable list view but not what i want.

kindly help me.

Answer (score 1):

use `setOnChildClickListener` to start a browser or start your downloading process

```
// Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)
                    + " : "
                    + listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition), 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

for more details and better tutorials follow [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/)

Comment: Actually using this tutorial i created the expandable list view. Sorry for noob question, can u plz tell me where to add the link in java code and in which java file or it should be added in strings.xml or anywhere else.